# How to check if a string contains at least 2 digits and no spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to build a program where you enter a password. The password must contain at least 8 characters, start with a letter, have both upper and lower case letters, have no spaces and at least 2 digits.

I have everything else down except for the last 2.

I tried using a for loop to see if there are spaces or digits, but it will only work if the whole password consists of spaces or digits. If there is a number or a space, if prints off the error message for as many characters there are in the password, not just for how many digits or spaces there are. I know this is happening because of the for loop, but I'm stuck on how to fix it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
again = 'y'
while again == 'y':
minimum_characters = 8
error = 0
print('Password must contain 8 characters, start with a letter,')
print(' have no blanks, at least one uppercase and lowercase letter,')
print(' and must contain at least 2 digits.')
password = input('Enter a password: ')
passlength = len(password)

#validity checks for errors
if passlength < minimum_characters:
    error += 1
    print (error, '- Not a valid password. Must contain AT LEAST 8 characters. PW entered has', passlength, '.')

if not password[0].isalpha():
    error += 1
    print(error, '- The password must begin with a letter.')

if password.isalpha():
    error += 1
    print(error, '- The password must contain at least 2 digits.')

if password.isupper():
    error += 1
    print(error, '- You need at least one lower case letter.')

if password.islower():
    error += 1
    print(error,'- You need at least one upper case letter.')


again = input('Test another password? (Y or N): ')
again = again.lower()
```

Comment: Also, a mandatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/936/) when speaking about good passwords. Please consider if you really have to require uppercase letters, numbers and no spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
if " " in password:
    error += 1
    print(error, '- Not a valid password. It contains spaces.')

if len([x for x in pwd if x.isdigit()]) < 2:
    error += 1
    print(error, '- The password must contain at least 2 digits.')
```

Answer (score 1):

User regular expression

```
import re
sequence = "1Sentence1e"
if re.match("(?:\d.*?){2,}", sequence):
  print("Match!")
else:
  print("Not match!")
```

Fiddle: http://tpcg.io/73SyIc

Regular expression match javascript syntax

Answer (score 0):

To report an error when the string contains less than 2 digits you can use:

```
if sum(map(str.isdigit, password)) < 2:
```

Also, your checks for uppercase and lowercase letters are incorrect:

```
if password.isupper():
```

checks if all characters are uppercase. To check if any character is uppercase you can use:

```
any(map(str.isupper, password))
```

Comment: I would change `if map(lambda x: x.isdigit(), password).count(True) < 2` to `if sum(map(lambda x: x.isdigit(), password)) >= 2` - it'll work for both Python 2 and 3, your version doesn't work for Python 3

Comment: Thanks, looks better.

Answer (score 0):

*"(...) have no spaces and at least 2 digits."*

A few options that will work for counting the number of occurrences of any character/digit. Simply replace with what you need (digits and spaces in the examples):

```
if any([x for x in password if x == " "]):
    # 1 or more spaces in password

if password.count(" ") > 0:
    # 1 or more spaces in password

if len([x for x in password if x.isdigit()]) < 2:
    # less than 2 digits
```